# Create suite from failed tests when running maven/surefire

Tags: maven, testng, surefire

I have a big test suite written in TestNG that takes several hours to complete.

I'd like for maven/surefire to create a new suite that is a copy of the first but with just the failed tests in it, a suite that should be much faster to run.

Is it possible to create such a suite?

As a fall back I could create it on my own from a test report that is easy to parse, if there is such report.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On completion of run, testng generates a testng-failed.xml (in the same output folder as your reports), which basically is your initial suite file with the listeners, but the tests part contains only the failed testcases.

In case you are using Jenkins, you might consider adding a postbuild step that triggers another build that works on the same workspace as the current build and uses this failed xml.  Or depending on how you are triggering your tests, you might look at writing a script to run the failed xml.